# Align text to bottom in a button and in front of background

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I align the text in the button to the bottom?

I tried to set `line-height` and `vertical-align: bottom;` in my CSS but neither worked.

**UPDATE:**

Also, I want the text to be **in front** of the background. I have set back gradients in the `normal`, `hover` and `active` states, so I my white text to be in front of that.

Code:

```css
.img-panel {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  color: white;
}

.img-panel:after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, color-stop(0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(40%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(100%, #000000));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 40%, #000000 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 40%, #000000 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 40%, #000000 100%);
}

.img-panel:hover:after {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, color-stop(0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)), color-stop(40%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)), color-stop(100%, #000000));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 40%, #000000 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 40%, #000000 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 40%, #000000 100%);
}

.img-panel:active:after {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, color-stop(0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)), color-stop(40%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)), color-stop(100%, #000000));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 40%, #000000 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 40%, #000000 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 40%, #000000 100%);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 img-panel-container">
    <button class="img-panel translucent-overlay-light" style="background-image: url('http://placeimg.com/500/300/any')">
      Hello
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

*For some reason bootstrap is not working in the code snippet*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a child element in your button (here a `span`) that you position to the bottom of the button.

Because the button is `position: relative`, the `span` with `position: absolute` will be position according to the button.

We also create a child element to display the background, via the `::before` pseudo-element selector.
To resolve which child will be display on top, between two `position: absolute` elements, the browser use the HTML/DOM order. So a `::before` element will be displayed below the others, while a `::after` will be displayed on top.
You also can force the stacking order with the `z-index` property.

```css
.img-panel {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
}

.img-panel::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 40%, black 100%);
}
.img-panel:hover::before {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 40%, black 100%);
}

.img-panel > span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<button class="img-panel translucent-overlay-light" style="background-image: url('http://placeimg.com/500/300/any')">
  <span>Hello</span>
</button>
```

Comment: I just noticed an error. The text is shifted a little to the right. Its not exactly in the center. :(
How can I fix this?

Comment: Okay got it. I needed to add
  `left: 0;`
`right: 0;`
  `text-align: center;`
Could you update your answer with the same

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Is it better?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `vertical-align: bottom;` but to do this you need to apply a `display:table` to the container and `display:table-cell` to the button and give him some specific height.

Take a look to this examples: http://daker.me/2014/04/4-css-tricks-for-vertical-alignment.html

Answer (score 0):

Place your button text in a span, give it absolute positioning and set `bottom` to `0`:

See the `.img-panel span.button-title` rule.

Update:

To place the text above the background, just add a higher z-index for the button text. A low number will do it.

```css
.img-panel {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  color: white;
}

.img-panel:after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, color-stop(0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(40%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(100%, #000000));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 40%, #000000 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 40%, #000000 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 40%, #000000 100%);
}

.img-panel:hover:after {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, color-stop(0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)), color-stop(40%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)), color-stop(100%, #000000));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 40%, #000000 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 40%, #000000 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 40%, #000000 100%);
}

.img-panel:active:after {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, color-stop(0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)), color-stop(40%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)), color-stop(100%, #000000));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 40%, #000000 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 40%, #000000 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 40%, #000000 100%);
}

.img-panel span.button-title {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 img-panel-container">
    <button class="img-panel translucent-overlay-light" style="background-image: url('http://placeimg.com/500/300/any')">
      <span class="button-title">Hello</span>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this:

```
<style>
span{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
</style>
```

And in html markup add:

```
<span>Hello</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.img-panel {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*If your button's height is 300px, you can try with a `padding-top` property :*

**CSS**:

```
.img-panel {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  color: white;
  padding-top:250px;
}
```

**Bootply** : http://www.bootply.com/AHSl2MVDIy